# Find the sum of angles without trigonometry?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, puzzle

I have found the sum it's $180$ but using right triangle and sine theorem.
[image]

Comment: @Subhadeep Dey yes

Comment: This boils-down to the same idea as in the question ["Show that the angles satisfy $x+y=z$"](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1605964/409), to which I gave [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1606045/409). The presentation may-or-may-not be distinct enough not to close this as a duplicate. (I'll leave that determination to others.)

Comment: Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5evLoL0xwg) which solves the problem without trigonometry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just rearrange them and notice that the bold triangle is right and isosceles:

[image]

Another proof of $\arctan 1=\arctan\frac{1}{2}+\arctan\frac{1}{3}$ comes from:

$$ (3+i)(2+i) = 5+5i $$

by switching to arguments.

Comment: where is the angle $x$ i can't see it.

Comment: @Mongol-genius: My yellow, green and red angles are the complementary angles of your yellow, green and red angles.

Comment: The green angle is $45^\circ$ because the bold triangle is right and isosceles.

Comment: i know it the angle $x=45^o$ but i thought if you rearrange the green yellow and red segments you have formed the triangle

Comment: @Mongol-genius: I do not understand what is the problem. You want to prove that $\arctan(1)+\arctan(2)+\arctan(3)=\pi$, and my picture above proves $\arctan 1+\arctan\frac{1}{2}+\arctan\frac{1}{3}=\frac{\pi}{2}$, that is clearly the same.

Comment: if you use arctan1+arctan2+arctan3=pi you actually use the trigonometry

Comment: @Mongol-genius: giving names to angles is using trigonometry? Well, then you want to prove that $$ yellow+green+red=\pi $$ and my proof shows that the complementary angles add to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/272250/44121

Answer (score 2):

Consider following triangle:

[image]

As $BC = AC$ we have $\angle ABC = \angle CAB$ or
$$
\pi - \gamma - \beta = \gamma - \frac{\pi}{2} + \beta \iff \gamma + \beta = \frac{3\pi}{4}
$$
(here $\gamma$ is red angle from picture in question and $\beta$ is yellow one). It's obvious that green angle from question (detote it as $\alpha$) is equal to $\frac{\pi}{4}$. Thus we have
$$
\alpha + \beta + \gamma = \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{3\pi}{4} = \pi.
$$

Answer (score 1):

@Jack D'Aurizio thanks for your solution and suggestions i found a little bit different solution from yours :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Draw a right triangle $ABC$ with the following properties:

$A$ is at the origin.

$C$ is the right-angle vertex at $(1,1)$.

$B$ is on your "left" as seen along a line of sight from $A$ through $C$.

$BC$ is twice as long as $AC$.

Then $B$ lies at $(-1,3)$ and the straight angle at the origin, in the upper half plane, is partitioned into $\arctan(1)+\arctan(2)+\arctan(3)$.