# Astonishing: the sum of two infinite products of nested radicals equal to $ \pi $.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry, pi, infinite-product

Recently, I found the following handwritten expression in an old math book of my family. Probably it belonged to my great grandfather Boris, who had a P.D. in mathematics.

$ \pi = \frac{4\sqrt{5}}{5}.\frac{2}{\sqrt{2 + \frac{4}{\sqrt{5}}}}.\frac{2}{\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 +\frac{4}{\sqrt{5}}}}}.\frac{2}{\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 +\frac{4}{\sqrt{5}}}}}}... +\frac{2\sqrt{10}}{5}.\frac{2}{\sqrt{2 + \frac{6}{\sqrt{10}}}}.\frac{2}{\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 +\frac{6}{\sqrt{10}}}}}.\frac{2}{\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 +\frac{6}{\sqrt{10}}}}}}... $

I found this identity extremely interesting, and, in fact, I had never seen it. It's similar, but different, from Vieta's formula for $ \pi $

How to prove this identity?

Comment: Long story short: through the cosine halving formula $$\cos(\theta/2)=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\theta}{2}}$$ and the telescopic product $$\cos(x)\cos(2x)\cdots\cos(2^N x) = \frac{\sin(2^N x)}{2^N \sin(x)}$$

Comment: The convergence is remarkably rapid; 2 parts in a million accuracy after just 7 terms, and the error seems to fall by a factor of about 5 each subsequent term..   Have you tried nesting similar but differently oriented  72-72-36 triangles in a circle?  [Of course, the REALLY astonishing result would be to show that this converges to something other than $\pi$, since it is so close.)

Comment: @SimpleArt: sure. That is exactly the principle behind Vieta's formula, not just "something similar".

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio Usually I can immediately see solutions given one of your hints, but this one has me stuck.

Answer (score 7):

Let $\theta=\arctan\frac{1}{2}$. Then $\cos\theta = \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$, hence $\sec\theta=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and
$$\cos\frac{\theta}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}},\qquad \cos\frac{\theta}{4}=\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}}}{2}}$$

and so on. Perform a bit of maquillage, then recall that
$$ \cos(\theta)\cos(2\theta)\cdots\cos(2^N\theta)=\frac{\sin(2^{N+1}\theta)}{2^N\sin(\theta)}$$
by a telescopic product, and you will recognize that your identity is just asserting
$$ \arctan\frac{1}{2}+\arctan\frac{1}{3}=\frac{\pi}{4},$$
[pretty well-known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1831908/find-the-sum-of-angles-without-trigonometry/1831927). Your grandfather just combined [a Machin-like formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machin-like_formula) with the principle behind [Vieta's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula) for $\pi$.

Comment: There's a nice proof without words (also well known) of that last fact: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j3SN.png

Comment: I see you've added in a link to some others. :-)

Comment: @BrianTung [Here is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWrQO.gif) another variation on the same theme ;-)