# Elementary trigonometric proof problem using multiple angles in the sine rule

Tags: trigonometry, proof-explanation

> In this diagram $AB=BC=CD=DE=1$meter,
>
> [image]
>
> Prove that $\angle AEB+\angle ADB = \angle ACB$

The method I used involved simple calculations using the sine rule and the pythagorean theorem, but I used a calculator, which isn't the most intuitive means of proving the statement, especially since the answer at the back of the book gave the following as a proof:

By the sine rule: $$\sin(180-\angle ADB - \angle AEB)=\frac{5\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\right)}{\sqrt{10}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$ $$180-\angle ADB - \angle AEB = 135^{\circ}$$ $$\implies\angle ADB + \angle AEB = 45^{\circ}$$ and $$\sin(\angle ACB)=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$ $$\angle ACB = 45^{\circ}$$

I feel like there is something very obvious that I'm overlooking, but I have yet to find it. My main area of confusion is how does $\displaystyle \sin(180-\angle ADB - \angle AEB)=\frac{5\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\right)}{\sqrt{10}}$.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: FYI: The puzzle itself appears in the question ["Show that the angles satisfy $x+y=z$"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1605964/409), and [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1606045/409) provides a trig-function-free solution.

Answer (score 0):

we have $$\tan(\alpha+\beta)=\frac{\tan(\alpha)+\tan(\beta)}{1-\tan(\alpha)\tan(\beta)}=\frac{\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{2}}=1=\tan(45^{\circ})$$

Comment: How does this clear up the area where my confusion lies?

Comment: you must use the tan-function, not sin

Comment: I believe that, if OP were asking for a solution to the puzzle, then the question should be considered a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1605964/409) (and your solution effectively duplicates [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1605984/409)). However, OP's specific concern is how a particular sine relation arises from the diagram. (Note: Your comment "you must use the tan-function" is an opinion apparently not shared by the author of OP's book.)

Comment: i don't know the author of OP's book

Comment: i think this is the easiest way to solve this problem

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: *Of course* you don't know the author. However, the solution *in the book* uses sine, and this is the source of the confusion for OP. Answers to the question should address that confusion, not offer alternative approaches to the puzzle (since these, as I mention, appear [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1605964/409) on MSE).

Comment: this is your opinion, i think it is better to take an easy way

Comment: i can add a proof by using the sin-function if you want

Answer (score 0):

I had thought that "sine rule" meant "Law of Sines", but perhaps not. Consider this derivation of the relation at issue:

$$\begin{align}
\sin(180^\circ-\angle ADB-\angle AEB) 
&= \sin(\angle ADB+\angle AEB) \tag{1}\\[4pt]
&= \sin \angle ADB \cos \angle AEB + \cos \angle ADB \sin \angle AEB \tag{2}\\[4pt]
&= \frac{|\overline{AB}|}{|\overline{AD}|}\frac{|\overline{AB}|}{|\overline{AE}|}+\frac{|\overline{BD}|}{|\overline{AD}|}\frac{|\overline{BE}|}{|\overline{AE}|} \tag{3}\\[4pt]
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} \tag{4}\\[4pt]
&= \frac{5}{\sqrt{5}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} \tag{5}\\[4pt]
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \tag{6}
\end{align}$$
These steps are consistent with the appearance of "$5/\sqrt{5}$" in the book's proof, so it may be what the author intended. Even so, going from the sine expression to Step $(5)$ is quite a conceptual leap. Moreover, as shown in some answers to [the puzzle as asked on MSE in 2016](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1605964/409) (and in [Dr. Graubner's solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2504616/409) here), a *tangent*-based derivation seems cleaner. (Of course, I believe a purely geometric approach [such as the one I provided](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1606045/409) is cleaner still, but I'm biased.) All in all, it appears that the author could've done a much better job with the explanation.

---

I'll note that this puzzle appears on [my Trigonography site](http://trigonography.com/2016/01/10/three-squares-puzzle/), which includes a reference to both [Numberphile's 2014 treatment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5evLoL0xwg), and [Martin Gardner's 1996 *Math Horizons* article](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/pubs/focus/MH_092010_GardnerEve.pdf) (which itself references a 1971 article by Charles Trigg(!), who found 54(!!) proofs of the relation).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I want to give a trigonometric and a geometric solution.

### Here is the trigonometric solution.

Clearly $\alpha = m\angle BCA = 45^\circ$

So we need to show that
$\beta + \gamma = m\angle BDA + m\angle BEA = 45^\circ$

Clearly $0 < \beta, \gamma < 45^\circ$.
So $0 < \beta + \gamma < 90^\circ$.

So, if we can show that $\tan(\beta+\gamma) = \tan 45^\circ = 1$,
then it will follow that $\beta + \gamma = 45^\circ$

\begin{align}
   \tan(\beta+\gamma) 
   &= \dfrac{\tan \beta + \tan \gamma}{1 + \tan \beta \cdot \tan \gamma} \\
   &= \dfrac{\frac 12 + \frac 13}{1 - \frac 12 \cdot \frac 13} \\
   &= \dfrac{\frac 56}{1 - \frac 16} \\
   &= 1
\end{align}

### Here is the geometric solution.

$\triangle ABE \sim \triangle AHG$

$\triangle ABD \sim \triangle GFA$

$m\angle HAF = 45^\circ = \alpha$

$\therefore \alpha + \beta = \gamma$.